# Android SAF get access to particular directory on SD Card

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-storage

I'm still searching, but maybe anyone faced with the same issue.
I'm maintaining an app. This app stores some data in two places (lets say on sdcard/example and external_memory/example). Before the migration to the newest Android Api everything worked fine using `ExternalStorage.getAllExternalStoragePaths()`. Now I'm still able to get both paths, but the sdcard/example path is not readable and not writable..

I read about the SAF, but in my case that is not a solution - the files stored in both directories are parsed using a native library (C++) - I need path to it like `/storage/sdcard/example/test.xml`. Otherwise the library is not able to read this file. Unfortunately I cannot change the library because of missing sources.

I would like to ask three questions:

- Is there any other way to ask access to directory on SD Card and use this directory like the old way?
- Maybe I can say Android - "hey, I want have Example directory on SD Card and maintain it"?
- Or maybe I can use SAF without ContentResolver?

Moving files to `/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example/files/` is not acceptable by stakeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other way to ask access to directory on SD Card and use this directory like the old way?

No, short of building a custom ROM or rooting the device.

> Maybe I can say Android - "hey, I want have Example directory on SD Card and maintain it"?

No. The closest thing is `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()`. If those return 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones will be on removable media, and you can read and write to those paths. However, you do not control what the paths are.

> Or maybe I can use SAF without ContentResolver?

No, insofar as you cannot get a filesystem path.

Comment: is it possible to write .nomedia file in SDCard silently. I don't want the user to see choose path dialog and all.